# Is there a way to automatically add timestamp of a file's last commit in Github README.md file?

Tags: github, readme

Suppose a Github repo has multiple files. In README.md, I can name those files and provide a link to each file as follows:

```
[test1.py](path/to/test1.py)
[test2.py](path/to/test2.py)
```

I would like to add the timestamp of when each of the file was last updated in the repo and show it along with the path to the file. I don't want to get the timestamp of the last commit in the repo, but only the timestamp of the last commit of each of the files separately

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  Git doesn't provide a way to automatically include generated information in files other than through the `ident` and `filter` functionality in `.gitattributes`, and outside of Git LFS files (which use the `filter` functionality), GitHub doesn't call any such functionality when rendering files.

Note that in general, READMEs are supposed to be simple markup-light (e.g., Markdown or AsciiDoc) files that people can read in a text editor or `less` as well as in rendered form, and aren't supposed to contain any sort of high-tech automated rendering.  That should be left to a project-specific website which can generate files as the project needs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Its good to know what can/can't be done within README.md

Answer (score 0):

@bk2204 points out very well that you cannot do that without preprocessing. Since similar needs are so frequent, I created a tool for such preprocessing.

You can use

https://github.com/verhas/jamal

editing your README.md.jam file. This file should contain your Markdown content enriched with the Jamal meta markup. Jamal processes the meta markup, and the output is the pure Markdown, which is then processed as it was manually created.

There are more than 200 different macro possibilities that you can use with Jamal. Out of the box, you can query the modification of a file and display it in the document using the `{@file (format=$time)fileName}` macro.

If you need something that does not exist, you can write your macro in Java or suggest the functionality. We may implement it for the next release if the functionality is general-purpose enough.